# Nutch regex doesn't crawl the way I want it to

Tags: regex, search-engine, nutch

Ok, I asked this already, but I guess I didn't ask it to the way stackoverflow expects. Hopefully I will get more luck this time and an answer.

I am trying to run nutch to crawl this site: http://www.tigerdirect.com/

I want it to crawl that site and all sublinks.

The problem is its not working. In my reg-ex file I tried a couple of things, but none of them worked:

```
+^http://([a-z0-9]*\.)*tigerdirect.com/

+^http://tigerdirect.com/([a-z0-9]*\.)*
```

my urls.txt is:

```
http://tigerdirect.com
```

Basically what I am trying to accomplish is to crawl all the product pages on their website so I can create a search engine (I am using solr) of electronic products. Eventually I want to crawl bestbuy.com, newegg.com and other sites as well.

BTW, I followed the tutorial from here: http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial and I am using the script mentioned in session 3.3 (after fixing a bug it had).

I have a background in java and android and bash so this is a little new to me. I used to do regex in perl 5 years ago, but that is all forgotten.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your comments I see that you have crawled something before and this is why your Nutch starts to crawl Wikipedia.

When you crawl something with Nutch it records some metada at a table (if you use Hbase it is a table named webpage) When you finish a crawling and start a new one that table is scanned and if there is a record that has a metada says "this record can be fetched again because next fetch time is passed" Nutch starts to fetch that urls and also your new urls.

So if you want to have just http://www.tigerdirect.com/ crawled at your system you have to clean up that table first. If you use Hbase start shell:

```
./bin/hbase shell
```

and disable table:

```
disable 'webpage'
```

and finally drop it:

```
drop 'webpage'
```

I could truncate that table but removed it.

Next thing is putting that into your seed.txt:

```
http://www.tigerdirect.com/
```

open regex-urlfilter.txt that is located at:

```
nutch/runtime/local/conf
```

write that line into it:

```
+^http://([a-z0-9]*\.)*www.tigerdirect.com/([a-z0-9]*\.)*
```

you will put that line instead of `+.`

I have indicated to crawl subdomains of tigerdirect, it is up to you.

After that you can send it into solr to index and make a search on it. I have tried it and works however you may have some errors at Nutch side but it is another topic to talk about.

Comment: Thanks, let me try this reg-ex. I delete all my solr data, so I know I don't have any records. The problem I am having now is I cannot find a way to crawl tigerdirect's product pages. The link to product pages is http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/category/guidedSearch.asp? followed by CatID, etc.

Comment: Solr's data and Nutch's data are at different places. Solr stores data under data folder of your solr home folder. Nutch stores at different place (i.e. webpage table of Hbase) On the other hand I see that the link to products maybe at different pages. i.e. http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=4840011&CatId=4678 is that one of what you want to index?

Comment: Ok, so if I run nutch a second time does it just append to the data it has already stored internally? Because when I clear the solr data and I run nutch, I only receive the data from the last crawl and not the previous ones.
As for what I want to do basically I want to create a search engine with indexed products from tigerdirect so I want to crawl tigerdirect once or twice a day to get all their product info. Right now I am just trying to create an index of their pages. Next I would like to pull data from each page (but this is not for this question) so I can display it in a meaningful way.

Comment: When you give a seed.txt Nutch puts them into its table(inject process of Nutch) Also when you crawl websites with Nutch it records everything in a table. When you run Nutch again first thing to do for Nutch is checking that table. Starts to check the URLs at that table. If next fetch time came for a URL Nutch crawls it. If not I think it logs that it will skip that URL. So when you point a new seed.txt to Nutch you inject new URL into Nutch. This is why you see some other URLs when Nutch starts to crawl.

Comment: @JuanAcevedo could you do it?

Comment: Hi kamaci, sorry I been so busy yesterday and today on another project. I will test this out tonight or tomorrow. I'll keep you posted. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Hi kamachi, I cannot find the command hbase. Can you tell me where it is?

Comment: Do you use Hbase to store your crawled documents by Nutch?

Comment: I am using nutch 1.X, should I be using 2.X? That is why I can't find hbase I think.Since my bounty is expiring, I will give it to you since  you answered the original question.

Comment: Which database did you choose to store crawled data of Nutch?

Answer (score 1):

You've got a / at the end of both of your regexes but your URL doesn't.

`http://tigerdirect.com/` will match, `http://tigerdirect.com` will not.

`+^http://tigerdirect.com/([a-z0-9]*\.)*`
Try moving that tailing slash inside the parens
`+^http://tigerdirect.com(/[a-z0-9]*\.)*`

Comment: Hi, thanks. It did not work however. Nutch still went ahead and crawled wikipedia. Any ideas why?

Comment: Wait, its crawling the wrong URL? One thing I noticed is tigerdirect urls do not contain only a-z0-9 in them. `http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/category/guidedSearch.asp?CatId=6838&cm_re=Homepage-_-Spot%2023-_-CatId_6838` you've also got to consider capitals, ?, =, &, %, -, and _. Your regex might be better `+^http://tigerdirect.com(/[a-zA-Z0-9-_&\?=%]*\.)*` (not sure if the ? needs to be escaped with this regex engine)

Comment: Ok, I think I need to add the rest in order to crawl what I want, but I can't even get that far. It crawled wikipedia as well with only the regex:
+^http://tigerdirect.com(/[a-z0-9]*\.)*

Comment: Wikipedia's URLs are nowhere near as complexly nested. What I dont understand is how it can say tigerdirect in the regex but still crawl Wikipedia

Comment: Ok, it was my mistake. I accidently left "+.", when I removed it now it doesn't crawl wikipedia, but nutch also doesn't crawl any http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/category/guidedSearch.asp? link. If you could help me with this, I can mark your answer as correct.

Comment: I looked at the nutch tutorial at http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial#A3._Crawl_your_first_website and it says you should just put `http://www.tigerdirect.com/` in the seed.txt, and then `+.` in the URL filters file. That should be it

Comment: It won't work because there are other links that will be taken that do not belong to the products pages. So basically it will index the whole page. But let me try it again and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: Just another random thing to consider, tigerdirect does have a robots.txt file which asks crawlers to not crawl certain parts of the site. Not sure if Nutch respects those areas, but they exist.